# Category & Subcategory page redirecting to 404 after installing a module-prestashop 1.6

Tags: apache, http-status-code-404, e-commerce, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

After installing `Module PrestaCenter XML Export Free (PS 1.5.x)` module to my **presta 1.6** shop i'm unable to visit any category & subcategory pages it shows

> error 404 page not found & product page says there is 1 error no
>   product found.

Home shows fine with products.

Please someone help me to find solution.

**i'm a beginner, but can go with step by step. any help will be appreciated**

I've tried disable enable friendly url,
checked all urls

`2017-07-23 13:02:49    Error   162.158.116.90      AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function getValue() on boolean in /var/www/vhosts/server1.buymebrand.com/httpdocs/modules/prestacenterxmlexportfree/classes/PcXmlFreeService.php on line 65\n', referer: http://www.buymebrand.com/editors/index.php?controller=PcXmlFree&token=2f4c14e9566a0ec5ce2a72c5364deb14             Apache error
2017-07-23 13:03:01 Error   162.158.116.90      AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function getValue() on boolean in /var/www/vhosts/server1.buymebrand.com/httpdocs/modules/prestacenterxmlexportfree/classes/PcXmlFreeService.php on line 65\n', referer: http://www.buymebrand.com/editors/index.php?controller=PcXmlFree&token=2f4c14e9566a0ec5ce2a72c5364deb14             Apache error`

Comment: Check error log and post that error here.

Comment: Thanks @Nimish. Error code have been posted please have a look.

Comment: Check line 65 in file `/modules/prestacenterxmlexportfree/classes/PcXmlFreeService.php`

Comment: i had uninstall & removed that module, so now what i do?  thanks for supporting @Nimish

Answer (score 0):

I have solve it.
First uninstalled the Advanced URL Module
Then Installed again

:)